# How to define new operators in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, operator-keyword

I want to define a a custom operator in dart，like:

```dart
condition ?: func();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for ternary operator? It works same as an if-else statement. Example:

```
condition ? funcConditionTrue() : funcConditionFalse();
```

Comment: I think, OP wants to avoid using ternary by defining a new operator that's like ternary but without the "if truthy" part

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky yes, so I have to define a new operator